# jakarta.servlet.ServletContext from jakarta.faces.context.FacesContext to getAttribute("AnAttributeName")

Tags: java, jsf, el, managed-bean

This is a piece difficult,It's JSF i'm using jakarta faces api 3.0.0 , it seems in a ManagedBean calling FacesContext to acquire the jakarta.faces.context.ExternalContext and use its getContext method that returns "java.lang.Object" that is either a PortletContext or a ServletContext (i'm not using neither need a portlet library) it does not respond or seem to gain the applications' running instance in Tomcat 10.
I need to obtain the proper instance of jakarta.servlet.ServletContext.
The docs do give reasons the ExternalContext getContext is not called except at startup or shutdown and does not make clear sense.
So shifting to another method that is called during operation from `ExternalContext getApplicationMap` a java.util.Map  and using `get "anobjectname"` did not operate either.

I need to access the class attributes i placed into the jakarta.servlet.ServletContext of the app as to that thereof in normal circumstance as always operates, `jakarta.servlet.ServletContext getAttribute "TheLoadedClassAttribute"`

The JSF page is XML and renders and calls the methods and shows but i cannot reach the proper ServletContext instance when i call these in the ManagedBean.
It also shows no error in the catalina.out log.

As you can see i've been shifting the code around this way and that but no result , but no error either !

```
package beans;
    
    
    import com.sun.faces.config.WebConfiguration;
    import jakarta.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
    import jakarta.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
    import jakarta.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
    //import jakarta.servlet.ServletConfig;
    import jakarta.servlet.ServletContext;
    import com.nicephotog.tools.objectattribute.WebAppToolRAMDataServingObj;
    import com.nicephotog.tools.objectattribute.objattrifc.RamStringB64;
    
    @ManagedBean(name="imagebytedatabean")
    @SessionScoped
    public class ImageByteDataBean{
    //ServletContext appconxt;  WebAppToolRAMDataServingObj dat;  RamStringB64 b64obj;
    //
    String imagedata;
    String testout;
    
    public ImageByteDataBean(){}
    
    
    public void setImageData(String imgNumber){
    // jakarta.faces-3.0.0-RC5.jar
     WebConfiguration wbc = WebConfiguration.getInstance();
    ServletContext appconxt = wbc.getServletContext();
    WebAppToolRAMDataServingObj dat = (WebAppToolRAMDataServingObj)appconxt.getAttribute("DataStoreObj");
    RamStringB64 b64obj = dat.getRAMStringB64Store();
    String idat = (b64obj.getRAMstringB64((int)new Integer(imgNumber).intValue()));
    System.out.println("begin idat in managed bean : "+idat);
    this.imagedata = idat;
    }
    
    
    public String getImageData(){
    return this.imagedata;
    }
    
    
    public void setTestout(String testout){
    this.testout=testout;
    }
    
    public String getTestout(){
    return this.testout;
    }
    
    
    }//enclss
    
    
    /*
    public void setImagedata(Integer imgNumber){
    java.util.Map appconxt = (java.util.Map)((jakarta.faces.context.ExternalContext)((jakarta.faces.context.FacesContext)jakarta.faces.context.FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()).getExternalContext()).getApplicationMap();
    WebAppToolRAMDataServingObj dat = (WebAppToolRAMDataServingObj)appconxt.get("DataStoreObj");
    RamStringB64 b64obj = dat.getRAMStringB64Store();
    String idat = (b64obj.getRAMstringB64((int)imgNumber.intValue()));
    System.out.println("begin idat in managed bean : "+idat);
    this.imagedata = idat;
    }
    */
```

HERE IS AN ERROR OUTPUT when @ManagedBean has parenthesized arguments to name the bean.

```
12-Nov-2022 03:46:05.050 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-3] com.sun.faces.context.SessionMap.put JSF1063: WARNING! Setting non-serializable attribute value into HttpSession (key: imagebytedatabean, value class: beans.ImageByteDataBean).
    12-Nov-2022 03:46:05.054 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-3] com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.handleRenderException Error Rendering View[/welcomeJSF.xhtml]
        jakarta.el.ELException: /welcomeJSF.xhtml: Method not found: class beans.ImageByteDataBean.testout(java.lang.String)
            at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:47)
            at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:42)
            at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UILeaf.encodeAll(UILeaf.java:170)
            at jakarta.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1454)
            at jakarta.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1454)
            at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:458)
            at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:164)
            at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:93)
            at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:72)
            at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:178)
            at jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:682)
            at jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:437)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
            at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
            at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:353)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:872)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1695)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    12-Nov-2022 03:46:05.078 1100 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.log JSF1073: jakarta.el.ELException caught during processing of RENDER_RESPONSE 6 : UIComponent-ClientId=, Message=/welcomeJSF.xhtml: Method not found: class beans.ImageByteDataBean.testout(java.lang.String)
    12-Nov-2022 03:46:05.078 1100 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.log /welcomeJSF.xhtml: Method not found: class beans.ImageByteDataBean.testout(java.lang.String)
        jakarta.el.ELException: /welcomeJSF.xhtml: Method not found: class beans.ImageByteDataBean.testout(java.lang.String)
            at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:47)
            at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:42)
            at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UILeaf.encodeAll(UILeaf.java:170)
            at jakarta.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1454)
            at jakarta.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1454)
            at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:458)
            at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:164)
            at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:93)
            at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:72)
            at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:178)
            at jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:682)
            at jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:437)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
            at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
            at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:353)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:872)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1695)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Following is its xml page , its only set for test output , the parameterized set method is able to inside or outside of an element and the whole process completes , but no result , but no error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
        <h:head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
            <title>JSP Page</title>          
      
        </h:head>
  <f:view>
        <h:body>

            <h1><h:outputText value="JavaServer Faces" /></h1>
    #{imagebytedatabean.testout('So heres some text to blow your mind!')}        
 <h:outputText value="#{imagebytedatabean.testout}" /> 
 <p />
            
 #{imagebytedatabean.imageData('4')}           
  
 <p />
<h:outputText value="#{imagebytedatabean.imageData}" />

       </h:body>
  </f:view>
    </html>
```

I obtained the FacesContext and classes it obtains that indicate or insinuate coherent association with the the overall application context the jakarta.servlet.ServletContext.

**SOLVED IT (mainly i should instantiated the properties) i simply could not understand the program flow of parameterized methods, so removed them (need to find good docs about parameterized EL methods), i'll just need to add another property to commit processing for page processing flow.**

**A good work around would/may be using WebConfiguration class to obtain the request parameters internally in the bean to obtain an image index with the postback url.**

```
    // jakarta.faces-3.0.0-RC5.jar   jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-2.0.0.jar   
    // jakarta.inject-api-2.0.0.jar   jakarta.annotation-api-62.jar
    // nicephotog-web-tools.jar   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gjHmdC-BW0Q2vXiQYmp1rzPU497sybNy/view?usp=share_link
    package beans;
    
    import com.sun.faces.config.WebConfiguration;
    import jakarta.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
    //import jakarta.inject.Named;
    //import jakarta.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
    //import jakarta.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
    import jakarta.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
    import jakarta.servlet.ServletContext;
    import com.nicephotog.tools.objectattribute.WebAppToolRAMDataServingObj;
    import com.nicephotog.tools.objectattribute.objattrifc.RamStringB64;
    // (name = "imageByteDataBean", eager = true) @ManagedBean(name="imagebytedatabean") 
    //@Named("imageByteDataBean")
    
    @ManagedBean
    @RequestScoped
    public class ImageByteDataBean{
    //
    String imagedata="4";
    String testout="Internal text value";
    
    public ImageByteDataBean(){}
    
    
    public void setImagedata(String imagedata){
    this.imagedata = imagedata ;
    }
    
    
    public String getImagedata(){
    makeImg(imagedata);
    return this.imagedata;
    }
    
    
    public void setTestout(String testout){
    this.testout=testout;
    }
    
    public String getTestout(){
    return this.testout;
    }
    
    public String makeImg(String umber){
/*
jakarta.faces-3.0.0-RC5.jar
 javax package is identical to jakarta except for javax package name
THIS OPERATES TOO - NOTE THE CAST (jakarta.servlet.ServletContext)    NOTE A CAST (javax.servlet.ServletContext)
jakarta.servlet.ServletContext appconxt = (jakarta.servlet.ServletContext)(jakarta.faces.context.FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()).getExternalContext().getContext();
*/
     WebConfiguration wbc = WebConfiguration.getInstance();
    ServletContext appconxt = wbc.getServletContext();
    WebAppToolRAMDataServingObj dat = (WebAppToolRAMDataServingObj)appconxt.getAttribute("DataStoreObj");
    RamStringB64 b64obj = dat.getRAMStringB64Store();
    imagedata = (b64obj.getRAMstringB64((int)new Integer(umber).intValue()));
    System.out.println("begin idat in managed bean : "+imagedata);
    return imagedata;
    }
    
    
    }//enclss
```

the test page xml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
        <h:head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
            <title>JSP Page</title>          
      
        </h:head>
  <f:view>
        <h:body>

            <h1><h:outputText value="JavaServer Faces" /></h1>
            
 <h:outputText value="#{imageByteDataBean.testout}" /> 
 <p />
                 
  
 <p />
<h:outputText value="#{imageByteDataBean.imagedata}" />

       </h:body>
  </f:view>
    </html>
```

Comment: Just wondering , would i need to use java.lang.reflect to obtain and load the running ApplicationContextFacade instance to get the main ServletContext. I'm using Tomcat 10 therefore  i do not use javax

Comment: nb: h:outputText value="JavaServer Faces" in the page prints and shows as everything else shows in "view source" , i know from earlier bloopers the methods ARE called , but now , i get no result and no errors printed. Another ? is the servletcontext i get from externalcontext a class representation of the instance that needs loading from class.forName to use it as an instance ???

Comment: Your question is pretty long winded and the general approach is unnecessarily overcomplicated, but in first place, did you know that the default managed bean name is `imageByteDataBean` with the 1st character lowercased, conform the Javabeans specification? You have there an outcommented `name="ImageByteDataBean"` which should have worked.

Comment: Thats interesting, because in the j2ee6 tutorial the UserNameBean class is spelled starting with uppercase and does not use AT ManagedBean annotation? Apparantly that works (Sun Micro.) Also @ManagedBean is deprecated in favor of AT named of recent. I just switched to jakarta.faces-3.0.0-RC5.jar that has com.sun.faces.config.WebConfiguration and the jakarta faces packages. Same result. I'll try putting the name = back

Comment: ...UserNameBean class in the xhtml code.

Comment: JSF 1.x used `<managed-bean>` entries in `faces-config.xml` instead of `@ManagedBean.` And indeed, it's in turn deprecated since JSF 2.3 in favor of CDI.

Comment: It is actually "not taking" on any of the methods while the AT ManageBean has the parenthesized arguments for name and or eager. Without it it pretends to not have an error. Finally errors have shown up warning about serializable and JSF in catalina.out

Comment: SOLVED IT and as usual its biting off too many things at once. It now gets the base64 image String from the ServletContext of the app outside Faces context and servlet from within faces. Uses com.sun in jakarta.faces-3.0.0-RC5.jar although the other jakarta  .jar without it i've yet to try. I had to remove the parameterized bean method calls, quite frankly i cannot find good docs to explain the program flow of parametized bean methods or whether they are set or get.